# How can I improve this stored procedure performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I am trying to speed up the execution time of my stored procedure. One inner join in particular is taking around 5 seconds to execute. I looked at the execution plan and it seemed the bottle neck was on an inner join.

I tried creating a few non clustered indexes as there was a 65% cost for an index seek (nonclustered).

Forgive me if I did not provide enough information as I am not that accustomed to using indexes in sql.

Here is the query that takes ~5 seconds to execute as the tables contain a lot of data:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_1(TBL2.COLA, TBL4.COLA, TBL4.COLB, TBL4.COLC, TBL3.COLA)
SELECT TBL2.COLA, TBL4.COLA, TBL4.COLB, TBL4.COLC, TBL2.COLB
FROM TBL_2 TBL2 with(index(idx_tbl2IDX))
    INNER JOIN TBL_3 TBL3 with(index(idx_tbl3IDX))
        ON TBL2.COLB = TBL3.COLB
    INNER JOIN TBL_4 TBL4 with(index(idx_tbl4IDX))
        ON TBL3.COLA = TBL4.COLD
            AND TBL4.COLA % 1000 = TBL3.COLC
            AND TBL4.COLE = 0
WHERE TBL2.COLC = 1
```

And here are my indexes (i originally just created one for TBL_4 since that is where the biggest cost in the execution plan was but i ended up creating one for each table to see if it made any difference, which it didn't

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_tbl4IDX]
ON [dbo].TBL_4(COLD, COLA, COLE)
INCLUDE (COLB, COLC);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_tbl3IDX]
ON [dbo].TBL_3 (COLB, COLA, COLC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_tbl2IDX]
ON [dbo].TBL_2(COLB, COLC)
INCLUDE (COLA);
```

I realize this may be a bit confusing as I renamed all the columns and tables, if it makes no sense please let me know and I will try and use better naming conventions.

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic since there is no "bug" per se in the code, it's just slower than the OP desires. I think this question is a better fit for dba.stackexchange.com. Their help page says that on-topic questions include "Database Administration including configuration and backup / restore,     Advanced Querying including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and query-performance"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps post the actual execution plan, but it's likely that this

```
AND TBL4.COLA % 1000 = TBL3.COLC
```

is causing the slowness.  The order of the columns in the index also might play into this, depending on how big your dataset is.  Try ordering them from Most to Least selective.  For instance, if TBL4.COLE is a 1/0 value and there are very few 0's, then perhaps make that the first column in your index.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing number of rows, selectivity etc. it is really hard to say anything. I would suggest

1. Remove all those `with(index...` (and never return them back)
2. Update statistics for all tables (e.g. UPDATE STATISTICS TBL_2 WITH FULLSCAN)
3. Add all possible indexes. There are 6 for tables TBL_3 and TBL_4 and two for TBL_2.
4. Run the query, see which indexes are used and what the time is.

If the time is ok, You can just delete indexes You do not need. If it is not, You would probably need to do something with the `% 1000`. You can make calculated persisted column and index that instead.